# Launch Android App When Clicking on a URL in the Mobile Browser

Tags: android

RE: [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser/12382173#12382173)

I have tried the approach as described in the above post, and it works perfectly if the URL is clicked on within an app such as G+, Twitter, etc. However, when I load a web page that contains the URL with the mobile browser (both android and chrome browsers), tapping on the URL doesn't launch the app.

Has anybody else seen this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already on a browser that can handle those links, most times (ever?) Android won't look for another app to handle that. I have seen this behavior and I don't think it can be changed.

Only way would be using your own schema, as already detailed in link you mentioned:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>

<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here">
```

However, this link wouldn't work on devices without your app. Is that acceptable for you?